# Facebook crawlers over angularjs app, javascript not loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My site is built with AngularJS and Worpress as a single page application and based on the page I'm routing I define appropriate meta tags in the controller. This is my HTML header:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="{{ngMeta['og:url']}}" />
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ngMeta['og:title']}}" />
<meta property="og:description" content="{{ngMeta['og:description']}}" />
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ngMeta['og:image']}}" />
```

This is working correctly, but I'm faced a problem when I'm trying to share a page on Facebook. Cause the crawler dispatched doesn't see the meta tags and this is what is returned:

[image]

I guess that this is because the crawler does not load the javascript, so the meta tags are not loaded.

How can I solve this, maybe working on the server side and use two different redirect (in the apache mod) one for human being and one for social inspection (facebook, twitter etc.)

EDIT:
I read an article in which they suggest to do a mod rewrite with apache that will handle the requests from the social media crawlers and redirect them to a server side static page with meta data handled by the server.

As already said I'm using wordpress with this permalinks `https://<dns>/%category%/%postname%/` and so this is my `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I should add something like this (each Rewrite url for each category):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteRule tracks/(\d*)$ https://<dns>/server/static-page.php?id=$1 [P]
RewriteRule articles/(\d*)$ https://<dns>/server/static-page.php?id=$1 [P]
```

To redirect the crowlers to the static page. But how can I handle the request in this server side static page? Do you have any suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved, basically you have to redirect all the crowlers of Facebook to a static server page, so you can enrich the open graph meta.

Wordpress does an implicit redirect to the `index.php` so you need also to block this redirect for Facebook (and all the social bots you want) in the `.htaccess`.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !facebookexternalhit/1.1|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} facebookexternalhit/1.1|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet
RewriteRule tracks/(.*) http://<fqdn>o/static.php?id=$1 [R]
</IfModule>
```

You can customize the RewriteRule for suite your permalinks (`tracks` is a category of my Wordpress) with all the regex you want. My custom permalinks of wordpress are built in this way: `/%category%/%postname%/`.

After you did the rewrite in the apache conf, you have to build your static page. I'm working with WP API V2 and this is my page:

```
<?php 

$SITE_ROOT = "http://<fqdn>";

$jsonData = getData($SITE_ROOT);
makePage($jsonData, $SITE_ROOT);


function getData($siteRoot) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $rawData = file_get_contents($siteRoot.'/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug='.$id);
    return json_decode($rawData);
}

function makePage($data, $siteRoot) {
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta property="og:type" content="articles" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $data[0]->link; ?>" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $data[0]->title->rendered; ?> | Going Solo" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $data[0]->excerpt->rendered; ?>" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $data[0]->better_featured_image->media_details->sizes->medium->source_url; ?>" />
        <meta property="og:image:width" content="500" />
        <meta property="og:image:height" content="500" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="<?php echo $data[0]->better_featured_image->media_details->sizes->medium->source_url; ?>">    
        <h1><?php echo $data[0]->title->rendered; ?></h1>
        <p><?php echo $data[0]->excerpt->rendered; ?></p>

    </body>
    </html>
<?php
}
?>
```

My `$id` is the slug of the post. If you then check you static page with the slug passed as parameters, you will see all the open graph meta handled via server side:

```
http://<fqdn>/static.php?id=<slug>
```

Comment: Also if you want include whatsapp crawler user agent add: WhatsApp/*